# program not giving desired output

Tags: python

I am new to programming and I am stuck with one of my programming assignments. please evaluate the given code and let me know the mistakes I have made. the code is expected to output the number of months required to save up to buy a new house...

```
total_cost = float(input("cost of house:"))
portion_down_payment= 0.25
current_savings = 0.0
r = .04
annual_salary = float(input("your annual salary is:"))
portion_saved = float(input("portion of income saved:"))   
months = 0

while current_savings <= portion_down_payment*total_cost:
   current_savings = current_savings*r/12 + portion_saved*annual_salary/12
   months = months+1
   
print("To buy your dream house you gotta wait for",months, "months")
```

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.  Your posted program hangs waiting for input.  Do not expect us to provide test data: simply replace your `input` with a test case that elicits the problem.

Comment: You've asked us to test your program, diagnose any and all errors, and fix them.  This is quite out of scope for Stack Overflow.  It is *your* job to isolate and exhibit a *single* problem, turning that into a *single* question.  Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 3):

You likely want to add to your savings, not overwrite them:

```
current_savings = current_savings*r/12 + portion_saved*annual_salary/12
```

should be:

```
current_savings = current_savings + current_savings*r/12 + portion_saved*annual_salary/12
```